# Set value on select options to select JSON data

Tags: javascript, html, json, api

I'm creating a select based on the JSON I got with an API. Based on that select, when I choose another option I want some data to change (text and image src).

I got the select with the options done. Each option is a name and I done that with forEach. My problem is setting the value so I can use it to change the other data. In my mind the easiest solution would be setting the value to the objects index so when I choose the first option I get 0 and can get the first JSON object. I'm not sure if this is the best way anyway.

This is my code reduced to only the forEach:

```
 <select name="select" id="selector"> </select>
```

```
  data_json.show.forEach((element) => {
    document.getElementById('selector').innerHTML +=
    `<option value="">${element.name}</option>`;
  });
```

(the value is what I want to be the same as the index of each json data)

My idea of what I want to get:

```
  <select name="select" id="selector">
    <option value="0">Name_01</option>
    <option value="1">Name_02</option>
    <option value="2">Name_03</option>
  </select>
```

So I can use the value like this:

```
  let titulos = document.getElementById("titulos");

  selectVal.onchange = function() {
        let actualVal = selectVal.options[selectVal.selectedIndex].value;
        titulos.innerHTML = "Títulos:" + " " + data_json.show[actualVal].image;;
    };
```

```
  <p id="titulos">Títulos:</p>
```

Hope it makes sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting them all to an empty value. You can use the array index to give them each a different value.

```
  data_json.show.forEach((element, index) => {
    document.getElementById('selector').innerHTML +=
    `<option value="${index+1}">${element.name}</option>`;
  });
```

BTW, you can simplify `selectVal.options[selectVal.selectedIndex].value` to just `selectVal.value`.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for this. I don't know why it got so difficult to find the array index. I ended up using it without the +1 so I get 0 on the first value and it finds the first value in the Json file. And thanks for the selectVal simplification too !